# Call another phone/text when bluetooth device goes out of range?

Tags: bluetooth

I want my phone to call another phone/text when a paired bluetooth device goes out of range. Is this possible – and if so, how to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if such an app exists, but I think MacroDroid can do this. Let me @beeshyams for this.

Comment: **C.W.:** Asking for app recommendations is off-topic here. I've slightly modified your question to avoid its closure – hope it meets your intention! As @iBug pointed out, some [tag:automation] apps could possibly do it.

Comment: @ Izzy I looked to see if that was one of the rules and could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) as an alternative .  I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being easy to learn and free (upto 5 macros)

First pair your devices and confirm

Create a macro

**Trigger:**  Bluetooth event  → Device disconnected → Select paired device

**Actions:**

1. Make call  → select number
2. Send SMS → Enter phone number and desired text (*Test* in screenshot below) on next line

**Constraints​ :** Leave blank

Name the macro whatever, save and profit

[image]

Tested on  Android 7.1.2

**Note:** Initiating call / SMS is not instantaneous on disconnection. There is a pause of about 30 seconds or so during which I *guess* Bluetooth connectivity is attempted again before it gives up and declares as *disconnected*

Comment: @iBug I was thinking of writing up something similar with [tag:tasker]. But as that's paid, I'm glad my wishes came true and someone posted the Macrodroid solution :)

Comment: Now I can buy the hardware and then test the software to see how it goes.