# Could I use a Bluetooth keychain (tracker) to track how many times a day an animal comes to eat on its food bowl (where I put a cellphone)?

Tags: bluetooth

I am researching wildlife rehabilitation and I would like to count how many times a day a released animal comes to eat on a food bowl left in the woods.

To do this, I am wondering if I could mark the animal with a Bluetooth keychain (tracker) on the animal's collar and then put a cellphone (the Bluetooth receiver) on a food bowl left in the woods, to register how many times a day (and what hour) the animal comes to feed after being released.

To do this, I think the Bluetooth reader app on the cellphone would need to operate in some kind of “always scanning mode”, in order to

1. catch the Bluetooth signal,
2. register the date and hour,
3. and then restart to scan for another signal without any human interference.
4. All day long until the phone (with a power bank) battery ends

Questions:

1. Could I use a Bluetooth keychain (tracker) to track how many times a day an animal comes to eat on its food bowl (where I put a cellphone)?
2. What Android app could do this job and generate such kind of report?

Comment: Automation is one option.  This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188129/131553) can be tweaked to meet specific needs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.